# PLsql equivalent query from PLpgsql

Tags: mysql, postgresql, mysql-workbench

I am new to mysql and used to work in postgresql. I have been trying to make a function in mysql workbench using plsql. I have written a code in plpgsql to describe what I want to do (basically data entry in a table avoiding the redundant entries)

I tried searching relevant answers and founds ways to delete duplicate entries from table. But, what I want to do is avoid duplicate data entry in the table. Following is the workable code but I don't understand how to get out of the loop if the update query runs successfully, if not, then insert query needs to be run. I know I can add IF-then-ELSE here. but what to write in the conditions.

```
DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE merge_abc
    (IN data CHAR(20))
    BEGIN
        LOOP
              UPDATE abc SET node_name = data WHERE node_name = data;
        END LOOP;
    END //
DELIMITER ;
```

*Aim is to avoid duplicate data entry rather than deleting the duplicate entries in the end just like this;

```
CREATE FUNCTION merge_abc(data TEXT) RETURNS VOID AS
    BEGIN
        LOOP
            -- first try to update the key
            UPDATE abc SET node_name = data WHERE node_name = data;
            IF found THEN
                RETURN;
            END IF;
            -- not there, so try to insert the key
            -- if someone else inserts the same key concurrently,
            -- we could get a unique-key failure
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO abc(node_name) VALUES (data);
                RETURN;
            EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
                -- Do nothing, and loop to try the UPDATE again.
            END;
        END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of running the update query is. Assuming you have a unique constraint, the catch for unique_violation should be fine. You might also consider using a MERGE statement

Comment: If you want to avoid duplicates just use the `UNIQUE KEY`. Searching for duplicates before insert is a) subject to race conditions, b) uses more CPU time. Avoid stored procedures they are hard, and unnecessary especially for simple cases.

Comment: PL/SQL is Oracle’s in-database programming language. If you are using MySQL then I can’t see how you could be using PL/SQL, unless I am missing something.